# JDA Discord bot to delete all messages from a text channel

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am trying for my JDA discord bot to delete all the messages from a text channel and I am using a highly inefficient code as of right now which occasionally works and occassionally doesn't. The code:

```
    {
        List<Message> msgs;

        msgs = textChannel.getHistory().retrievePast(50).complete();
        textChannel.deleteMessages(msgs).queue();
    }
```

I know for a fact that I am calling the function and I know for a fact that the textChannel being passed is the correct one.
Please do help me with the same.

Comment: That would be impossible if the text channels contains messages that are more than 14 days old. That is because bots cannot delete messages that are 14 or more days old, see https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#bulk-delete-messages. A workaround is to clone the channel and delete the old one. (See the top answer)

Comment: Bots can delete messages that are older than 14 days, they just cannot bulk delete them in one request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest and most efficient way I could think of, would be to clone the Channel and delete the old one.

Try something like this:

```
textChannel.createCopy().queue();
textChannel.delete().queue();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution to your problem:

```
MessageHistory history = MessageHistory.getHistoryFromBeginning(channel).complete();
List<Message> mess = history.getRetrievedHistory();
for(Message m: mess){
   m.delete().queue();
}
```